# How to store dyanamic value into jquery cookie variable

Tags: jquery, html, cookies, dhtml

How can we store dynamic variables into cookie .

```
var username = ($("#username").val());
```

how to store the variable username into jquery cookie variable

```
$.cookie('username', '+username +');
alert($.cookie('username'));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you put within a single quotes it takes only string.So for this you don't need the single quotes for assigning the value.

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var username = ($("#username").val());
    $.cookie('username', username ); 
    alert($.cookie('username'));  
});
```

It works for me.