# an audio is playing and you reload the page but the audio should start from that point where the page was reloaded

Tags: javascript

How to start playback of audio from a specific time point?

let suppose an audio is playing, you reload the page and the audio should resume from that point where the page was reloaded. I already have code storing the time as audio plays, but I don't know how to use that value as new audio start time.

```
        li = $('#plList li').click(function () {
            var id = parseInt($(this).index());
            if (id !== index) {
                playTrack(id);
            }
        }),

        loadTrack = function (id) {
            $('.plSel').removeClass('plSel');
            $('#plList li:eq(' + id + ')').addClass('plSel');
            npTitle.text(tracks[id].name);
            index = id;
            audio.src = mediaPath + tracks[id].file + extension;

            // Assign an ontimeupdate event to the video element, and execute a function if the current playback position has changed
            audio.ontimeupdate = function() {myFunction()};

            function myFunction() 
            {
                // Display the current position of the audio.
                $('#cookieVal').val(audio.currentTime); 
                localStorage.setItem("audioPlayTime", audio.currentTime);
                console.log(audio.currentTime);
            }
        },

        playTrack = function (id) {
            loadTrack(id);
            audio.play();
        };
    extension = audio.canPlayType('audio/mpeg') ? '.mp3' : audio.canPlayType('audio/ogg') ? '.ogg' : '';
    loadTrack(index);
}
```

Comment: how do you play your audio?

Comment: through javascript in a simple way

Comment: i need a full fledge ans for that because i m so stuck in this thing

Comment: You could store `.currentTime` in localStorage (or cookie) and readout after page load.

Comment: I have done the .currentTime but I m beginner so don't know much

Comment: @RanaHaseeb MDN does have great docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/currentTime

Comment: @RanaHaseeb Show some code !

Comment: i have added my code please have a look at it

Answer (score 0):

You could use `currentTime` property. Store `currentTime` in localstorage or cookie.

This question already answered . You can find more detail . Check this out at this link [Setting HTML5 audio position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9563887/setting-html5-audio-position?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Answer (score 0):

## Hello!

It's really hard to say how to do it without me seeing your code, but I'll give you steps that I would try that could make you achieve this!

**note that I am not sure if this is the best way to do this!**

**1.** Use **onbeforeunload** event to check when user is leaving the page.

**2.** When this event triggers, save the time and the song to a cookie variable [here you can see how](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3758180/how-to-store-dyanamic-value-into-jquery-cookie-variable)

**3.** And finally use **DOMContentLoaded** event, so when your page loads, you try to load those variables you saved into cookies.

**4.** If they exist, **you've got your time**, just play your song from that time, if not, just start from 0:00.

---

### I'm sorry...

But I can't provide you with ready code, cause you didn't show any either.
But I hope that you'll find my answer somewhat useful! Cheers!